# Error while capturing packets from raw socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to run the following lines of program:

```
import socket
import struct
import binascii

sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(0x800))
print sock
```

I get the following error:
Message File Name   Line    Position
Traceback
        C:\Users\d\Documents\rawsocket.py   19
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PF_PACKET'

I am using Pyscripter, Python 2.7 on windows 8.1

Thanks!

Comment: `PF_PACKET` is only available on Linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should use `AF_INET` on windows for opening raw sockets. something like:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
```

Comment: That was helpful. now my next error comes at the following line:pkt = sock.recvfrom(2048)...Is this again somthing not supported in windows ?

Comment: This seems to be true for Macs as well.